# React: Async from class to functional

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning React and so far I'm liking it. But the problem is that most of the tutorials are old and still using old states instead of hooks.

Now when I'm following a tutorial, I'm trying to convert the code I see into hooks. For now I'm really stuck and could use some help for this code. I'm trying to convert the code bellow for a functionnal component. I tried using `useEffect` but it didn't work.

```
handleChangeOrder(oldIndex, newIndex){

if (oldIndex == newIndex) {return;}

const [todos] = this.state;

let newSequence =[];

todos.forEach((todos,index)=> {
    newSequence.push({id: todo.id, order: index + 1 });
});

}    
-------------------------------------------
static changeTodoOrderURL(){
return apiDomain + "api/todo/reorder";
}
----------------------------------------
async changeTodoOrder(order){
const url = UrlService.changeTodoOrderUrl();
try{
const response = await HttpService.post(url,{order});
return response.data;
} catch (error){console.error("Not able to change order of the todos")};
}
```

**What I tried so far in converting it :**

```
function handleChangeOrder(oldIndex, newIndex) {
    if (oldIndex == newIndex) {
        return;
    }
    const todos = Array.from(todolist);
    let newSequence = [];
    todos.forEach((todos, index) => {
        newSequence.push({id: todo.id, order: index + 1 });
    });


  
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/todo/reorder')
    .then(response=>{
      setList(response.data);
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  },[])


}
```

I'm struggling mainly with `async changeTodoOrder`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use useEffect to send API requests based on event change, useEffect used to send API requests/perform side effect based on state change or on the mounting of the component.

Also, you can't call the hooks inside a function, by using it this way you are breaking the rules of hooks.
please review the rules of Hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

based on your code above from the class component you can use it as it is without using useEffect

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think you are right about the hook it should not be inside the function. But other than that do you any idea about "changeTodoOrder" on how to make it into the functional ?

Comment: changeTodoOrder is a normal regular function, where are calling this function?

Comment: I using axios to fetch data, and I didn't understand this line "const response = await HttpService.post(url,{order});"

Comment: can you paste the whole code or use codesandbox

Comment: Sorry it's not my code, just a youtube video I'm following https://youtu.be/AMBqcJ7tykI?t=569

Comment: so HttpService probably is just an abstraction for the axios setup and this is just sending a post request to send the data to the API with the `order` object as the body of the request

Comment: Aah now I get it. I may have some idea now to proceed, thank you.

Comment: @AlyaKra are you familiar with the relation between the server and the client and the HTTP methods? we use get to get the data from the API, and the post to send the data to the API

Comment: Yes I'm a little bit familiar with the restful stuff, I'm using laravel for backend, but i'm struggling in frontend.